# How do I remove S3 webpage Redirection Rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-301

I created a redirect rule in the S3 console with the following logic:

```json
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "category/coins"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "cat/coins.html"
        }
    }
]
```

After saving, it redirects:

```bash
https://www.example.com/category/coins
```

to

```bash
http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cat/coins.html
```

I went back into the console and deleted the rules, but this redirection stayed.

I just want to delete the rule and need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this myself. It may be the browser caching the response.

After removing the rules, on a normal tab it keeps going to `cat/coins.html`.
[image]

However, in incognito it immediately remains at `category/coins`.
[image]

Comment: Incognito tab for the win.   Thanks!